# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects

Tags: python, django

the following code:

```
 data = {"url": 'http://test.com/unsub/' + request.user.pk}
 print(data)
```

Gives me this error:

> > TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects

Unsure why?

Comment: When you get an exception, it's often helpful to try a search engine. If you search for "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects", the first page is full of explanations of this problem.

Comment: because a long and a str cannot be concatenated, that's why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably because `request.user.pk` is an integer and not a string, and you can't concatenate strings and integers (or long integers).

Use this instead (I'm an old-fashioned guy, I prefer the old syntax):

```
data = {"url": "http://test.com/unsub/%d" % request.user.pk}
```

Comment: Stringformatting fits well in here and I would not not consider this old-fashioned. This solution is clean and well readable as well!

Comment: Indeed, but the str format function has been added in Python 2.6, and I like the old C-like style better.

Answer (score 3):

Its because pk is an integer and the other one is a string

```
data = {"url": 'http://test.com/unsub/' + str(request.user.pk)}
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `request.user.pk` is a long and the python `+` operator doesn't like that.

Try `str(request.user.pk)` instead.